# Use of in clause value to another sql query

Tags: mysql

I have one variable:

```
FarmerServiceID+= "'"+tabledata1.get(k)+"',";
```

My problem is: the values which are coming `tabledata1.get(k)` ends with ','
and what happens is I use this `FarmerServiceID` in the following query.

```
select farmerid from tblfarmer where farmermapid in("+ FarmerServiceID+");
```

> error: syntax error near ')'

I know error is coming because of ','
How do I remove this error?

Comment: write full query? what return tabledata.get(k)

Comment: tabledata.get(k) returns  three values '2465','5265','123', but at the last it comes with , . i want this , should be removed. if i do so, it just take only one value in the In clause.

Comment: get(k) is a function in mysql ?

Comment: k is variable used for "For Loop"

Comment: You need to show us more code other than this snippet.  You are omitting critical information needed to render a useful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error occurs because of your **FarmerServiceID** has a **,** (comma) at the end of the string.

I will suggest you to remove the **comma** at the end of the string before you do the SQL query.

```
FarmerServiceID += "'"+tabledata1.get(k)+"',"; 
FarmerServiceID = FarmerServiceID.substring(0, FarmerServiceId.lastIndexOf(',')); -- Remove the comma at the end of the string
```

Then do your SQL Query

```
select farmerid from tblfarmer where farmermapid in("+ FarmerServiceID+");
```

Comment: when i use this : values comes in table.get(k) ='123','456','23288',
error  :-You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''23288)' at line 1

Comment: thanks aton @webster it worked!!! god bless!! my work was stucked because of this!! thankalot!! :) :)

Comment: Anytime dude :). Cheers.